# Why would the report in SSRS show #error but in Visual Studio pro 2013 would not?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, reporting-services, compatibility

I have the following expression in one of my reports.

```
="Average " & formatNumber(cstr(avg(fields!TrueCycleTime.Value)),0)
```

When I preview it in VS 2013, the output is fine but in SSRS some of the rows (not all) show #error.

Comment: It might have to do with the unnecessary **CSTR** conversion. I don't see any reason for it - have you tried removing it?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a formatNumber. But you make sa cstr just before : I don't think you need the formatNumber. Just the cstr.